# Why are my 2 xml layouts not weighted evenly when they are the same?

Tags: android, xml, layout

In these 2 layouts I have they are setup identically.  The only difference between the 2 is that the text in 2 of them is different.  I have the layouts that the texts are in setup to only take up 25% of the width but yet just due to text lengths it screws some things up.  Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

The layout on top

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/blankRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/levelOneLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/levelOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/level_1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/perLevelLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/perLevel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/per_level" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chosenLevelLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And right underneath this I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Health"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/health"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/healthLevelOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/healthPerLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/healthAtChosenLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your layout has too many `LinearLayout`, remove those which wrap `TextView`, you don't need them to get the layout you want.
2. Remove `android:width="wrap_content"` and add `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to all of your `TextViews`.

Like :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levelOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/level_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/perLevel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/per_level" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
```